# Reasons of sub-linear speedup in parallel programs

Tags: erlang, multicore, parallel-processing, performance

What are the reasons a parallelized program doesn't achieve the ideal speedup?

For example, I have thought about data dependencies, the cost of data transfer between threads (or actors), synchronisation for access to the same data structures, any other ideas (or subcategories of the reasons i mentioned)?

I'm particularly interested for problems occurring in the erlang actor model but any other issues are welcomed.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl's_law

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few in no particular order:

1. Cache line sharing - multiple variables on the same cache-line can incur overhead between processors, even if the theoretical model says they should be independent.
2. Context switch overhead - if you have more threads than cores, there will be overhead in context switching.
3. Kernel scalability issues: kernels may be fine at say 4 cores, but less efficient at 8.
4. [Lock conveying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lock_convoy)
5. [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law) - The limit of the parallel speed up of a program is the proportion of the program that can parallelized.

Answer (score 4):

One reason is that parallelizing a program is often more difficult than one imagines and there are many subtle problems which can occur. For a very good discussion on this see [Amdahl's Law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in the Erlang Actor model is that each process has its own heap of memory and messages passed are copied around. Contrast with the usual way of using shared memory where you can pass a pointer to a structure between processes.

In a shared memory environment, it is up to the programmer to ensure that only a single process/thread operates on a piece of memory at a time. That is, some process is designated as *it* and has responsibility for doing the right thing on that memory area. Not so much in Erlang: One process *can't* by *design* rummage in other processes memory areas and you must copy values to other processes. This is tremendously powerful when we consider robustness of programs, but not so much if we consider the speed by which the program executes. On the other hand, if we want a distributed environment of multiple computers, *copying* reigns king and is the only way to transfer data between machines.

Amdahl's law comes into play because parts of your program may be impossible to spread out over multiple cores. There are some problems which are inherently serial in nature: You have no hope of ever speeding them up. Usually they are iterative where each new iteration is dependent on the former and you can't make a guess at the new one.